# Having trouble syncing my package-lock.json file with my package.json file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

Hello im trying to deploy a cloud function to google firebase. However I keep running into this error. It seems that my package-lock.json and my package.json files are not in sync. Here is the error message for reference:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/core@7.22.20 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @ampproject/remapping@2.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.22.15 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helper-module-transforms@7.22.20 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helpers@7.22.15 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: gensync@1.0.0-beta.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json5@2.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/compat-data@7.22.20 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helper-validator-option@7.22.15 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: browserslist@4.21.10 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: lru-cache@5.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helper-module-imports@7.22.15 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @babel/helper-simple-access@7.22.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: caniuse-lite@1.0.30001538 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: electron-to-chromium@1.4.525 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: node-releases@2.0.13 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: update-browserslist-db@1.0.11 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
```

I've tried removing the node modules and package-lock.json and then running 'npm install'. I've done this process both in my root directory and in my functions directory. The functions directory is where my backend is located. However, the error message will not disappear. Is there anything else I should try? Should I try running 'npm ci'? I'm really not sure what that will do.

I've been trying to solve this problem for two weeks now and still can't figure it out. I've even tried asking chat GPT but still I can't resolve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

**Edit1: Showed the error message in text instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Ok thanks, I made the appropriate changes